# Representation Of Linear Velocity as Cross Product

Tags: velocity, conventions, rotational-kinematics, rigid-body-dynamics, angular-velocity

Why is *linear velocity* represented as **cross product** of **angular velocity of the particle and its position vector? Why not vice versa?**
(*Consider rigid body rotation*)

Comment: Are you asking why velocity is given by $v = \omega \times r$ rather than $v = r \times \omega$?

Comment: yes!if you know the answer please let me know!

Comment: I think it's just because we conventionally take anti-clockwise angles to be positive. I can't think of any deeper reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I'm assuming you want the formal proof of this well known kinematics formula! So here goes:
[image: This is UCM with respect to a stationary axis.]

Let the particle rotate about the axis OO' ...
Within time interval $dt$ let its motion be represented by the vector $d\varphi$ whose direction is along axis obeying the right-hand-corkscrew rule, and whose magnitude is equal to the angle dφ.

Now, if the elementary displacement of particle at a be specified by radius vector $r$,

From the diagram, it is easy to see that, for infinitesimal rotation, $dr= d\varphi\times r \tag{1}$

By definition, $ω = dφ/dt$

Thus taking the elementary time interval as $dt$, all given equations surely hold!

Thus we can divide both sides of the equation $(1)$ by $dt$ which is the corresponding time interval!

So we get $dr/dt = dφ/dt \times r$   of course $r$ value won't change WRT the particle and axis, so $r$/dt  is essentially $r$!

So result is, $$\boxed{v = ω \times r}$$

Comment: And just so u know, if u tried v = rXω, that would be fundamentally wrong, bcuz of how the direction of ω us assumed by the right hand rule convention!, then of course you would obtain an illogical result, anyway , that's if u go by convention!!

Comment: Ok then basically i've been questioning the right hand screw rule itself..and do you know a proof for the right hand screw rule? Btw this is a good approach :-)

Comment: The right hand screw rule is just convention; we could define the cross product the opposite direction and it would be fine as long as the same new version was applied universally

Comment: @VIVID, Sir, would you please elaborate why $dr=d\phi × r$

Comment: @Rahul If you treat that as a normal triangle (i.e. nothing about infinitesimal rotation) $dr = r\sin\phi$. But $\sin\phi \approx \phi$ for sufficiently small angles

Comment: I find the differential approach unnecessary here -- unless I'm missing something, here is the derivation I prefer: the radius of the rotation circle $R$ is clearly given by: $R=|\vec{r}|\sin{\theta}$. Where $\theta$ is the angle $\vec{r}$ makes with the $z$ axis. Now, writing the velocity's magnitude as $|\vec{v}| = wR = w|\vec{r}|\sin{\theta}$, we observe that if we define $\vec{w} = (0,0,w)$ this is the unique vector such that $|\vec{w} \times \vec{r}| = wR = |\vec{v}|$. Finally, we also observe that as a vector $\vec{v}$ is perpendicular to both $\vec{w}$ and $\vec{r}$ and we're done.

Answer (score 1):

$\omega$ is a axial vector, not an ordinary or polar vector, and its sense depends on the handedness of the coordinate system.  For a right handed coordinate system v=ω×r.  See the textbook   Symon Mechanics.